# bash scripts to compile and run C++

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

I'm trying to get into C++ but its annoying to have to run things through the command line with wordy commands so I wanted to make a bash script to simplify the process and run these commands

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "start" ]; then
    cd CCPP
    cd HelloWorld
    g++ -Wall -W -Werror main.cpp -o HelloWorldCPP
    ./HelloWorldCPP
```

But I've never worked with bash before and hacked it together from someone elses code. Its not working, but I have no idea why as I don't know enough.

Comment: Have you considered using a makefile?

Comment: Use an IDE, it does that kind of stuff automatically

Comment: Also, the script is correct. What error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error /home/adam/CCPP/HelloWorld/crunner.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: how does one make a make file?

Comment: fi is missing at the end

Comment: @user2137452 It can be quite complicated, but getting started is easy. Just search for stuff like `makefile tutorial`.

Comment: Elaborating "Its not working" with "1. What command did you try? 2. What error/unexpected-behaviour did you observe?" can help.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing `fi` at the end, but you could also write a GNU Makefile like this:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall
OBJS=main.o
EXECUTABLE=main

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@


clean:
        rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
        rm -f $(OBJS)

main.o: main.cpp
```

Note, this is a flexible example, and you could simplify this even further down the line. Here you can find a very good tutorial to read upon:

http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

However, I would strongly suggest to learn cmake instead as writing Makefiles manually are painful.

A CMakeLists.txt file could be something like this:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

then simply:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake ../ && make VERBOSE=1
```

and then you would be done in a cross platform way as GNU Makefiles only work on Unices. You would need to adjust that for Windows and so forth to get it work. cmake is freely available pretty much everywhere needed, and it has proper support for native builds, cross compilation.

This forum also has a cmake tag with several people around to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I use mrkite's "edit-and-compile" approach as described in http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12301

It only needs a magic incantation at the top to declare it's a bash file, then gcc is invoked with any and all flags you want and set to read from the current file. A single magic word at the end makes it stop scanning; and after that, you can immediately run the compiled code, or do anything else.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/gcc -xc -o howareyou - <<EVILEOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("this is so wrong\n");
}
EVILEOF
./howareyou
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jongware thanks! I first saw that [bitcoin.c](https://github.com/mzerter/FALCON/blob/master/bitcoin.c) was using that, but version suggested by you makes use of doc-here in bash! great!

I have improved it a little. Now you can compile both

```
sh program.cpp
```

and

```
g++ program.cpp -o program && ./program
```

```
#if 0
#set -e
#process substitution
#ls . | cat EQUALS cat <(ls .)
#But this does not always work, so we have to use regular one
( cat <<COLLECTDATAMAGICKEYWORD
#line 9
#endif
#include <iostream>
#define COLLECTDATAMAGICKEYWORD
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout<<(char*)(void)"Hello World"; //Intentionally throws warning so you can see #line 9 works! 
    return 0;
}
COLLECTDATAMAGICKEYWORD
#if 0
) |\
 sed '2d' |\
 sed '1a \ "'"$(echo "${0}" | sed 's#\\#\\\\\\\\#g')"'"' |\
 sed '1N;s#\n##' |\
 g++ -xc++ -o program3 -
./program3
#endif
```