# Compiling and running C++ code with one command in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

My question is simple: Is there a way to compile and run c++ code from the terminal in Linux in one line?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419973/bash-scripts-to-compile-and-run-c

Comment: `make execute`, assuming you make the appropriate changes to your makefile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
g++ myfile.cpp -o myfile && ./myfile
```

Comment: Not really one command.

Comment: @JohnDibling The OP specified "one line" as well as "one command" in the question.

Comment: OP asked for _one line_, not _one command_ (the latter doesn't even make sense in `shell` terms: technically the command above is still a single command)

Comment: Hmm the title and question are slightly different..

Comment: @AlexanderL.Belikoff:  Take another look at the question title.

Answer (score 8):

Try this hack:

Stick this line on the top of the cpp file:

```
//&>/dev/null;x="${0%.*}";[ ! "$x" -ot "$0" ]||(rm -f "$x";g++ -o "$x" "$0")&&exec "$x" "$@"
```

Then add execute permission on the cpp file, i.e. (`chmod +x foo.cpp`), then:

```
./foo.cpp
```

Comment: Horrible, albeit interesting (hence the +1), solution! It also doesn't quite satisfy the OP's question since it requires multiple commands the first time any .cpp file is created.

Comment: @JBentley, hehe, it's not meant to be for proper use, but it's useful for little test snippets... About commands, that's splitting hairs... ;)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Assuming your c++ program is coded in a single file called foo.cpp:

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo && ./foo
```

Note: the && means: execute the command on the right only if the command on the left succeeded

Comment: +1 for thinking the same and "make && ./foo" if the program is not in a single file (and you need a makefile)

Comment: Makefiles don't have to be real files - they can arrive via stdin and bash here strings.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20006901/2113226

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a shell-scripting question than a C++ question. There are many ways of chaining commands in most shells. Assuming you're using bash (try `echo $SHELL` to make sure), take a look at a good [bash tutorial](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php).

Answer (score 3):

*By "one command", I am assuming the OP means invocation of exactly one binary from the command line.*

In one line: yes; see other answers.

In one command: sure - you can take advantage of some [make](/questions/tagged/make) implicit rules, and push in your own run rule via a bash here string:

```
$ ls hello* *ake*
ls: cannot access *ake*: No such file or directory
hello.c
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%s %s\n", "hello", "world");
    return (0);
}
$ make hello.run -f - <<< 'hello.run: hello; ./$<'
cc     hello.c   -o hello
./hello
hello world
$
```

Answer (score -1):

In one line: yes; see other answers.

In one command: no.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20006901/2113226 how to do this in one make command

Comment: @DigitalTrauma It's clever yes but not literally one command.